# Circular animation in Apple watch using UIGraphicsContext

Tags: objective-c, uikit, watchos-2, uigraphicscontext

I want to create circular animation in Apple watch using Core Graphics. I want to create an animation like Earth is revolving around the sun continuously. I have tried the method below but it crashes the application on watch after some time. Please share your suggestions and ideas on this.

Attempt:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextSize);
CGContextRef context    = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

[sprite.image drawAtPoint:sprite.position];

// Convert to UIImage
CGImageRef imgRef       = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
self.lastImage          = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];

// End the graphics context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self.container setImage:self.lastImage];
```

1. `TGESprite` is my own custom class having an two objects **1.
   UIImage** and **2. CGPoint** its position.
2. In above code I find the point of a circular path of a specified
   radius and draw image on that series of position after a regular
   interval of time.
3. When I try to smooth the animation and reduce the interval time to
   25 times in a second. It only runs for two iterations and then
   crashes.
4. In nutshell, I want to create a circular animation in which I have a
   complete control of object that is revolving.

Comment: Provide details about the crash.

Comment: Xcode gives no detail. After couple of iterations Application stops running on Apple Watch and Log says "Program exits with error code 0". But it is still running in Xcode. I then need to again launch the app by tapping icon from Apple Watch and again Xcode starts showing logs and again after couple of iterations it stops by saying "Program exits with error code 0".

Comment: Are you releasing the imgRef after creating the UIImage?